# after closing jquery mobile popup lick gets clicked below it

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing jquery mobile app using phonegap. I have on scenario where i enter zipcode in popup and if its invalid, I show another popup. But when I click on close button of second button it oprns link below it on page.
I am using jquery mobile 1.4
thank you

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle of your problem? Without it our answers would just be guessing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the propagation of the click events through the different layers of the page:

```
$('.element').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //do your stuff
});
```

That way the layer below will not receive the click.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am stiff facing the issue, not in every click... but if i do repeated clicks then it opens the same link again. If i add alert in the click event then it works properly but without alert it takes me to next page